# STDERR: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Brlapi==0.7.0 ERROR: No matching distribution found for Brlapi==0.7.0

Tags: python-3.x, serverless, aws-serverless, dynamo-local

when running sls deploy, I'm getting this error. I tried checking my Ubuntu version and its package details. Everything seems to be fine.I have Ubuntu 20.04 and python 3.8.5 installed on my system.Can someone help me on this?

Comment: are you using pip to install brlapi ?

Comment: i'm installing it using the sudo apt install python3-brlapi...and when i check the installed version its correct but still its not working.

Answer (score -1):

update apt and install brlapi

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-brlapi
```

run `pip list` to check if its installed

```
pip list
```

```
anti@Datakriya:~$ pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- --------------------
apturl                 0.5.2
attrs                  19.3.0
Automat                0.8.0
awscli                 1.19.15
bcrypt                 3.1.7
blinker                1.4
boto3                  1.17.2
botocore               1.20.15
Brlapi                 0.7.0
```

Comment: I would recommend using a Virtual environment to install packages

Comment: i tried these steps and when i do pip list its showing brlapi 0.7.0 but still i'm getting the same error when deploying